# CRUD methods in custom Swift classes

Tags: ios, swift, oop, swift2, crud

I'm wondering if it's a good idea to include CRUD methods inside custom Swift classes, or are they better off in a separate class?

For example I have a class called User.swift:

```
class User  {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var id: int
}
```

Now, would it be okay to include the get and create methods here? These methods will make API calls via Alamofire:

```
class User  {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var id: int

    static func add(user: User) -> User {
        let parameters = ["firstName": user.FirstName , "lastName": user.LastName]
        return sendRequest(.POST, url: "example.com/users", parameters: parameters)
    }

    static func getById(userId: Int) -> User {
        return sendRequest(.GET, url: "example.com/users/\(userId)")
    }
}
```

Should these methods be in a separate class, like in an ApiHelper class?

My application passes around the User object in arrays and dictionaries in several places, so wondering if it's good to keep it clean with just the properties.

Answer (score 1):

I think better declare such methods in some ApiHelper/Router singletone class, as well as they must work async, work with some parse system (RestKit probably) and return fetched objects via closures with some delay

Answer (score 0):

The different opinions about the right approach often causes a heated discussion. And this also extends to questions whether we should perform validation in the model class (`User`) or in the controller, how we should handle versions, serialisation, errors, undo/redo, locking, asynchronicity, etc., etc.

And the resulting code should still be clean, comprehensible, extensible, testable and put into a library so that we can reuse it in other projects!

IMHO, there's no right approach. IMHO, I would start with the following principles:

Your `User` class is seen in your solution as an `Entity`. An entity has a property `ID` and possibly other principal methods, for example, it exposes an `init` which takes a dictionary of attributes where the class/struct instance can be initialised.

That entity also knows about a "Persistent Store", so your `User` class may also conform to a protocol "Storable", which exposes class and instance methods like `save`, `create`, `update`, `delete`, `query`, etc.

This is only the tip of an iceberg what comprises a complete solution. You might look how others have solved this problem. For ideas, see

- Use Core Data objects which you populate from the JSON
- Implement the [Active Record Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)
- Look at some Object Relational Mappers (there are a lot of implementations and libraries). Even though, you need to map from JSON to Objects, these gives some hints.
- If you are still not satisfied, take a look at ASP.NET

Leveraging the "Active Record" approach you may start with something like this:

```
public final class User {
    public init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
    public var firstName: String
    public var lastName: String
    public internal(set) var id: Int
}


protocol ActiveRecord {
    static func create(object: Self) throws -> Self
    static func fetch(id: Int) throws -> Self
    static func update(object: Self) throws -> Self
    static func delete(id: Int) throws 
}

extension User: ActiveRecord {
    static func create(object: User) throws -> User {
        ...
    }
    static func fetch(id: Int) throws -> User {
        ...
    }
    static func update(object: User) throws -> User {
        ...
    }
    static func delete(id: Int) throws {
        ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that useful info. So, if I follow the ActiveRecord approach, will that have any performance impact? For example, if I create an array of Users, each user in that array also has references to the protocol methods. Or is that not a big deal?

Comment: @Prabhu No, there's no such thing like a reference to the protocol. There's also no performance impact due to using a protocol and an extension. However, this simple approach has sever limitations, for example its _synchronous_. A synchronous API may be suitable for servers accessing a local database. Its not particularly useful for web service APIs. Here, you would make it asynchronous and provide a means for cancellation as well. It's a very broad topic, so this above snippet is just a starting point for further ideas. Perhaps, in your case, Core Data would be suitable.